# Answering a tip for golfing in a specific version of a language

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tips

Phrased generally, my question is: Given a language "The Summer" and an experimental branch of it "The Fall", should I answer a "Tips for golfing in The Summer" question with an answer written in "The Fall"?

Here's my specific dilemma:

I was considering adding a tip about golfing in [Dotty](https://dotty.epfl.ch/) to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala) about tips for golfing in Scala, but I'm unsure of what to do, because I don't know if a tip for Dotty should be added to a question about Scala. Even though Dotty is slated to become Scala 3, it's not quite the same language as Scala 2, and some of its features may be dropped later.

The way I see it, I have 3 options:

- Answer the question linked above. Pros: Potentially helps someone. Cons: Answer may be invalidated by future changes or confuse people using Scala 2.
- Make a question about tips for golfing in Dotty. Pros: Not polluting the original question. Cons: It's going to be even harder finding those tips, and they may later have to be moved to the original Scala question somehow.
- Do nothing. Pros: No harm done. Cons: I won't be able to share my vast amount of expertise with the rest of humankind.

None of those please me. Which would you suggest?

Update: Following Bubbler's advice, I have taken the second option and made my own [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210491/tips-for-golfing-in-dotty) for Dotty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Post a separate golfing tips question for Dotty, and rename it later if necessary

This has been done for [Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/78410) when [ES6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624/78410) was introduced. Also there's [Raku (formerly Perl 6)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17732/78410) which diverged from [Perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5105/78410), and also [the title was changed when Perl 6 was renamed to Raku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/17732/revisions).

Definitely when a language evolves, we have some new golfing tips and some deprecated ones. Skimming through the first page of Dotty docs, it looks like it has *a whole lot* of differences from previous Scala, which seems more than enough to warrant a new tips question. When it becomes a new major release of Scala, you can rename the post's title as such.

Comment: That makes sense, especially considering that others have done the same. I'll wait a day to see if any other answers pop up, and if not, I'll accept this and make a new question.